# How to find statement causing "The user does not have permission to perform this action." in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: security, azure-sql-database, errors, audit

I ran a Kusto query:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) 
| where Category == "Errors" and error_number_d == 297
| summarize  count(), min(TimeGenerated), max(TimeGenerated) by Message, LogicalServerName_s, DatabaseName_s, query_hash_s
| sort by count_ desc, max_TimeGenerated desc, Message
```

I had some results, which included query_hash_s values. I can convert them from decimal to hex, but of course they don't show up in Query Store or the plan cache because they never actually executed.

I looked at the Audit records using the Query Editor, but it couldn't find any rows where the statement did not succeed for the appropriate database:

```
SELECT TOP 100 event_time, server_instance_name, database_name, server_principal_name, client_ip, statement, succeeded, action_id, class_type, additional_information
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('<REDACTED>', default, default)
WHERE succeeded != 'True'
ORDER BY event_time DESC
```

How can I find the statement text, and information about the user who attempted to execute it, for each of these errors?

Comment: I don't work with Azure, but it seems to have extended events like on-prem. You could try tracking failing queries with them. Here is code I use [link](https://adbsql.blogspot.com/2019/07/finding-failing-queries-in-sql-server.html). Should help you get started.

Comment: @rois That's definitely true, but you need to set up an EE Session in advance per database and capture future events. I am trying to analyze things that have already occurred over about 800 databases.